# Expand function in terms of complicated auxiliary variable?

Tags: functions, symbolic

I have the following two-variable function involving a large product:

```
Z[p_, q_] := (p^(-1)*(1 - p)^2)*
    Product[((1 - p*(q)^m)^2*(1 - p^(-1)*q^m)^2)/((1 - q^m)^4), {m, 1, 200}];
```

and I'm hoping to take the following expansion in the variable `q` where the coefficients are functions of the variable `p`:

```
Series[Z[p, q], {q, 0, 5}]
```

However, I actually would like the coefficients of this expansion to be not functions of `p`, but rather of the auxiliary variable

```
z = p^(-1)*(1-p)^2
```

Is there a nice, clean way to carry this out? I think I would know what to do if I could solve for `p` in terms of `z`, but that clearly won't work here. I should also mention that I'm only thinking of this as a *formal* object I'm expanding, so I definitely don't want to worry about whether or not things are honest "functions", branch cuts, or anything like that!

Comment: Can't you do a `/.` replace?

Comment: @Feyre That won't do 'cause `/.` seeks for exact patterns like in a `FullForm`. So `FullSimplify @ Series[Z[p, q], {q, 0, 1}] /. p^(-1)*(1 - p)^2 -> z` does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question right, I see no big problem here.
Solve p as a function of z and substitute.

```
    In[6]:= sol = Solve[z == p^(-1)*(1 - p)^2, p]

Out[6]= {{p -> 1/2 (2 + z - Sqrt[z] Sqrt[4 + z])}, {p -> 
1/2 (2 + z + Sqrt[z] Sqrt[4 + z])}}

 In[30]:= ser1[q_, z_] = 
  Series[Z[p /. First@sol, q], {q, 0, 5}] // Normal // FullSimplify

Out[30]= z - 2 q (1 + 2 q) (1 + q + 2 q^2 + 3 q^3) z^2 + 
 q^2 (1 + q (8 + q (23 + 56 q))) z^3 - 2 q^4 (1 + 6 q) z^4

 In[31]:= ser2[q_, z_] = 
  Series[Z[p /. Last@sol, q], {q, 0, 5}] // Normal // FullSimplify

   Out[31]= z - 2 q (1 + 2 q) (1 + q + 2 q^2 + 3 q^3) z^2 + 
    q^2 (1 + q (8 + q (23 + 56 q))) z^3 - 2 q^4 (1 + 6 q) z^4
```

Solution ser1 and ser2 are equal.

```
   In[32]:= ser1[q, z] - ser2[q, z] // Simplify

  Out[32]= 0

 In[33]:= ser1[0, z] // Simplify

  Out[33]= z

   In[34]:= Plot3D[ser1[q, z], {q, -2, 2}, {z, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. Here is your expressions:

```
   Z[p_, q_] := (p^(-1)*(1 - p)^2)*
   Product[((1 - p*(q)^m)^2*(1 - p^(-1)*q^m)^2)/((1 - q^m)^4), {m, 1, 
     200}];

expr = Series[Z[p, q], {q, 0, 5}] // Normal;
```

This expresses `p`in terms of `z`:

```
sl = Solve[z == p^(-1)*(1 - p)^2, p][[1, 1]]

(*  p -> 1/2 (2 + z - Sqrt[z] Sqrt[4 + z])  *)
```

and this substitutes:

```
  expr1=expr /. sl // Simplify

  (*   (1/((2 + z - 
      Sqrt[z] Sqrt[4 + z])^4))2 (z - Sqrt[z] Sqrt[4 + z])^2 (-2 - 9 z - 
       6 z^2 - z^3 + 3 Sqrt[z] Sqrt[4 + z] + 4 z^(3/2) Sqrt[4 + z] + 
       z^(5/2) Sqrt[4 + z]) (-1 + 2 q z - q^2 (-6 + z) z - 
       8 q^3 (-1 + z) z + q^4 z (14 - 23 z + 2 z^2) + 
       4 q^5 z (3 - 14 z + 3 z^2))  *)
```

Here is the coefficient of the expansion for, say, q^5:

```
 Coefficient[expr1, q^5]

(* (8 z (3 - 14 z + 3 z^2) (z - Sqrt[z] Sqrt[4 + z])^2 (-2 - 9 z - 
   6 z^2 - z^3 + 3 Sqrt[z] Sqrt[4 + z] + 4 z^(3/2) Sqrt[4 + z] + 
   z^(5/2) Sqrt[4 + z]))/(2 + z - Sqrt[z] Sqrt[4 + z])^4    *)
```

Have fun!